# Without using callback, I only get the first 100 of data in sqlite

Tags: c++, database, sqlite

I have successfully gathered codes from here in stackoverflow, and managed to create this simple codes. The aim is to list the rows of data without their column names.

Somehow it works, but it prints only the first 100 of rows. The remaining 4 rows did not print.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <sqlite3.h>

sqlite3 *db;

int rc;

char *sql;

sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

int main()

{

    rc = sqlite3_open("PairToSqliteDB.db", &db);

    if (rc)

    {

        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));

        return (0);

    }

    else

    {

        fprintf(stderr, "Opened database successfully\n");

    }

    sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "select Item_id, ItemName, SellPrice from SARISARI", -1, &stmt, NULL);

    int c = 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < SQLITE_ROW; i++)

    {

        rc = (sqlite3_step(stmt)) == SQLITE_ROW;

        // %.2f = two decimals

        // %6.2f = six digit right align with two deci.

        // %-12s = twelve char left alignment

        if (i % c == 1)

            printf(" | ");

        printf("%3i: %-12s = P%6.2f", sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0), sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1), sqlite3_column_double(stmt, 2));

        if (i % c == 1)

            printf("\n");

    }

    sqlite3_close(db);

    return 0;

}
```

the result is below:
`Opened database successfully

1: Marlboro     = P  8.00 |   2: Mighty       = P  7.00

3: More         = P  7.00 |   4: Camel        = P  6.00

5: Mrlboro Pak  = P160.00 |   6: Mighty Pak   = P130.00

7: More Pak     = P130.00 |   8: MrlboroPakRT = P145.00`
and so on upto 100, then the remaining items did not print.

Comment: `SQLITE_ROW` is a constant with the value 100, so you can't use that in a for loop. The idea is to use a while loop and test whether `sqlite3_step()` returns a row or not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read data from SQLite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957343/how-to-read-data-from-sqlite-database)

Comment: @Marijin, thanks for info, i have seen so many uses "while loop" and it works fine. but my aim is to produce and output with two rows per line using code "int c = 2; if (i % c == 1) printf("\n");, <-- it produce endline after two rows of data that works in "for loop".

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution which again from someone who posted here in stckoverflow, just could not remember who posted it.
With some manipulation of his codes, i made it work for my purpose.
As what suggested, i have to use while loop. Thanks for him.

Changes on my codes herebelow:

`
sqlite3_stmt *stmt = NULL;
int rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "select Item_id, ItemName, SellPrice from SARISARI", -1, &stmt, NULL);
if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
return rc;

```
const unsigned char *valChar;
const char *columnName;
double valDouble;
int valInt, type, colCount, colIndex;
int rowcount = -1;
int c = 2;
rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
while (rc != SQLITE_DONE && rc != SQLITE_OK)
{
    colCount = sqlite3_column_count(stmt);
    for (colIndex = 0; colIndex < colCount; colIndex++)
    {
        rowcount++;
        type = sqlite3_column_type(stmt, colIndex);
        columnName = sqlite3_column_name(stmt, colIndex);
        if (type == SQLITE_INTEGER)
        {
            valInt = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, colIndex);
        }
        else if (type == SQLITE_FLOAT)
        {
            valDouble = sqlite3_column_double(stmt, colIndex);
        }
        else if (type == SQLITE_TEXT)
        {
            valChar = sqlite3_column_text(stmt, colIndex);
        }           
    }
    if (rowcount % c == 1)
        printf(" | ");
    printf("%3i: %-12s = P%6.2f", valInt, valChar, valDouble);
    if (rowcount % c == 1)
        printf("\n");
    rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
}
rc = sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
return rc;
```

}`